# Создание двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, typescript

Имеется метод для создания нулевого двумерного массива, нужно избавится от for, подскажите пожалуйста какие есть способы?

```
createNewMatrix(row: number, column: number){
        let arrayInit: number[][] = [];
        for(let i: number=0; i<row; i++){
            arrayInit[i]=[];
            for(let j: number=0; j<column; j++){
                arrayInit[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        return arrayInit;
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте в описание тэг с названием вашего языка на котором вы пишете

Comment: это либо `js + flow`, либо `typescript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот функция без цикла

```js
function createNewMatrix(row, column) {
 var arr = Array(row).fill().map(() => Array(column).fill(0));
        return arr;
}
console.log(createNewMatrix(3, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

От одного оператора цикла вам не избавиться, от второго можно избавиться так:

```js
function createNewMatrix(row, column) {
    let arrayInit = (new Array(row)).fill().map(()=>new Array(column).fill(0));
    return arrayInit;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(createNewMatrix(3, 6)))
```

Comment: я написал на js так как в момент написания ответа не был указан язык, переведи сам код в typescript